# How do you see whats in a channel with Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am working with nodejs on Windows 7 and have a client which publishes a message and another which subscribes to it. Currently I am not doing anything with the message that is published. In other words there is no client1.on("message",...) method to handle the message.

I maybe wrong but I thought that even though I am not processing the message the message must stay in a durable queue?

If so how can I see what is in the queue?

I just started looking at the Redis api, and I could not see any commands to view a channel.

Comment: Redis publish and subscribe channels are not implemented using queues. There is no queue you can browse to see the items. All received items are immediately sent to all the interested clients. Except for socket buffers, they are not kept, queued, or journalized. If a client is not listening, or cannot fetch an item, it will be lost for this client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I may have got confused whilst I was reading about Redis MQ (from ServiceStack) and there I believe they talk about durable queues. So durable queues is not part of Redis, right?

Comment: Actually, you can build durable queues with Redis (leveraging the list datatype), but they are not tied to the publish/subscribe interface.